# Cannot launch AVD in emulator for Windows 8.1 Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Good day.
I have a problem with my Android studio emulator. I've searched the internet and I can seem to find the solution to this problem.
Whenever I try to launch my emulator, this is what I get:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator. 
 Output: 
 emulator: WARNING: cannot find system DNS servers! Name resolution will be disabled. 
 emulator: WARNING: cannot find system DNS servers! Name resolution will be disabled. 
 ###WARNING: will use system default DNS server 
 ###WARNING: unable to configure any DNS servers, name resolution will not work 
 Hax is enabled 
 Hax ram_size 0x40000000
 Hax is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
```

The emulator then starts, but the app refuses to run. Any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved. 
I just connected my system to the Internet then restarted Android studio. 
I don't know what in the world happened but it works now.

What am I doing....